# how to clear old text on p5js canvas

Tags: p5.js

```
var j=0;
    function keyPressed() {                 
            word[j] =key;
            j++;

            if(keyCode == BACKSPACE){           
                shorten(word);
                shorten(word);
                arrayCopy(word, contents);          
            }
            else{
                contents=key;
            }

    }
    function draw(){
        text(contents, pos_x, pos_y, 300, 300); 
        pos_x = pos_x + textWidth(contents);
    }
```

when i am using backspace key,i use shorten() to remove the last element of array.how to put this new text on the canvas,without calling clear() and background().

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Why do you not want to use the `background()` function? That's usually exactly how you would handle this.

Comment: when we use background() function ,other drawing on the canvas  disappears,To regenerates the drawing , if we try createGraphics() function, off-screen graphics buffer,performance issues will appear.please suggest the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already outlined both of your options.

**Option 1:** Every frame, call the `background()` function to clear out old frames, and then draw everything again.

**Option 2:** Draw the stuff you never want to clear to an off-screen buffer using the `createGraphics()` function. Then every frame, clear out old frames, draw the off-screen buffer to the screen, then draw the "dynamic" content on top of that.

You're going to have to try both approaches and be more specific about exactly what "performance" you're afraid of. But in general, the above two approaches are exactly how you'd deal with this problem.